# Getting TypeError with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to implement the latest version of React Router (v.4.3.1) in Material UI Tabs, but getting the following error:  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`. I believe I need to use some sort of location history, but not sure of the implementation given the updates to React Router.

**UPDATE**

I've managed to fix the location of undefined issue and get the navbar and content to show by using `BrowseRouter as Router`, but now the navbar links are not showing in the navbar. There isn't any logic to show or hide the links, so not sure whats causing them to not show up.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Main from './Main';
import { Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      appTitle: "App"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = this.state.appTitle;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
       <Router>
         <Switch>
           <Route component={Main} exact path="/" />
         </Switch>
       </Router>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { NavBar } from "./Components/Navbar/";

const GetNavBar = props => {
  return (<NavBar appTitle={props.appTitle} />);
}

const Main = props => {
  return (
    <div className={props.classes.root}>
    <GetNavBar appTitle={props.appTitle} { ...data.appHeader } />
    <GetPageComponents {...props} data={data}/>
    </div>
)};

Main.propTypes = {
  onClose: PropTypes.func
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Main);
```

**Navbar.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Tabs, Tab } from 'tabs';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const TabLink = linkProps => (
    <a {...linkProps}>{linkProps.linklabel}</a>
);

function renderTab({ getTabProps }) {
const { className, label, ...rest } = getTabProps();
return (
    <Tab
        className={`${className}`}
        component={TabLink}
        linklabel={label}
        to={TabLink}
        {...rest}
    />
 );
}

renderTab.propTypes = {
   getTabProps: PropTypes.func
};

const NavBar = ({onChange, onDeselect, classes}, props) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.headerContainer}>
    <AppHeader
        data-testid="app-header-default-example"
        position="static"
        className={styles.root}
        getTabProps={({ getTabProps }) => (
          <div {...getTabProps({})}>
          <Router>
            <Tabs>
              <Tab label="Home" component={renderTab} exact to="/" />
              <p className={styles.headerAppTitle}>{props.appTitle} . 
              </p>
            </Tabs>
          </Router>
          </div>
        )}
      />
    </div>
)};

NavBar.propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    onDeselect: PropTypes.func
};

export default withStyles(styles)(NavBar);
```

Comment: Nothing in this code block is referencing location. Can we see the `Main` Component?

Answer (score 3):

With React Router 4.x, try changing your import to something like the following to import a higher-level router such as [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter). This example is using an alias `Router` to refer to the named import `BrowserRouter`, but it's not necessary, you could just use `BrowserRouter` without the alias:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Technically you can import [Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router), but that would be from `react-router`, not `react-router-dom` and you would usually separately create a [history object](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router/history-object) for it:

```
import { Router } from 'react-router';
```

That being said, you are most likely looking for `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom`, but there are other options such as [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter).

**Updated**

Regarding the `NavBar` component. You are also trying to import `Router` from `react-router-dom` and use `Router` in it's markup. First you would need to remove that import and `Router`, as it's not needed. If the goal is to use material-ui `Tabs`/`Tab` as navigation, you would need to use `Link` components instead of `<a>` elements for the `TabLink` component.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// ...

const TabLink = linkProps => (
  <Link {...linkProps}>{linkProps.linklabel}</Link>
);
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/3ujwqz-oclxvw) demonstrating the functionality at a basic level.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Alexander - I managed to fix that location error by using `BrowserRouter as Router`, but now the links don't show in the navbar. I've updated my code above and a further explanation. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: It looks in `NavBar` you are also trying to import `Router` from `react-router-dom` and use `Router` in the render method. You need to remove that import and `Router`. Also you'd need to change the markup of the tabs to use `Link` components. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating so quickly. I've made your recommended changes, but still not getting the tabs rendered into the DOM. The Navbar itself is, but the tabs are not. Any further ideas? Thanks for the continued help!

Comment: You may need to fork the StackBlitz referenced in the answer and add your additional code to allow additional troubleshooting. You may need to share your `AppHeader` code as well to understand how that is rendering `Tabs` and how `getTabProps()` is working. That being said, make sure you aren't using `BrowserRouter` anywhere other than `App`. If I had to guess it's surrounding `getTabProps()`.

Comment: I'm able to add another `<Route />` to App.js and change the url to access that view, but getting `<div class="[object Object]">` where the tabs should be within the navbar.

Comment: Sounds like progress is being made. I'd really recommend you try to make a working example for troubleshooting. The issue is with how `AppHeader` and `renderTab()` are working together. If you just straight add `<Tab label="Item One" to="/" component={TabLink} linkLabel="Home" />` similar to the example I created, it would probably render. It's tough to debug without a working example.